# Google My Business - Unable to remove likes

Tags: local-seo, google-local-search, google-my-business

Recently ive been liking some positive reviews on a local listing, while browsing same reviews few weeks after the likes wont appear as mine.

When you like a review a blue thumbs up appear on that review, but after few days the like is still in place but the blue thumbs up is now grey, like you would see a like from different user.

Im using the same account the likes were made, is Google making likes permanent after specific time or is this some sort of bug?